# Error when Deploying Asp.net core Application with multiple Solution on Bluemix

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, ibm-cloud, devops, asp.net-core-1.0

When i try to Build & Deploy Asp.net core application with multiple solution on Bluemix, Getting following error log:

```
-----> Restoring dependencies with Dotnet CLI

   log  : Installing BundlerMinifier.Core 2.0.238.
   error: Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 supports:
   error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
   error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
   error: One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
   log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools' in /tmp/staged/app/src/MyProject.Utility/project.json...
   log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools' in /tmp/staged/app/src/MyProject.Core/project.json...
   log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools' in /tmp/staged/app/src/dotnetCloudantWebstarter/project.json...
   error: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 1.0.0 supports:
   error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
   error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
   error: One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.

   error: Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports: netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
   error: Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports: netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
   error: Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports: netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
   error: Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports:
   error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
   error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
   error: Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports:
   error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
   error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
   error: Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports:
   error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
   error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
   error: One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
   log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools' in /tmp/staged/app/src/MyProject.Utility/project.json...
   error: One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
   log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools' in /tmp/staged/app/src/MyProject.Core/project.json...
   error: One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
   log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools' in /tmp/staged/app/src/dotnetCloudantWebstarter/project.json...
   log  : Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures 1.0.0.
   log  : Installing MyCouch.Cloudant 4.0.0.
   error: Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 supports:
   error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
   error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
   error: Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 supports:
   error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
   error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
   error: One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
   error: One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
   error: Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 supports:
   error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
   error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
   error: One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
   error: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0 supports:
   error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
   error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
   error: Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports: netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
   error: Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports:
   error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
   error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
   error: One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
   log  : Writing lock file to disk. Path: /tmp/staged/app/src/MyProject.Core/project.lock.json
   log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools' in /tmp/staged/app/MyProject.Core/project.json...
   error: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0 supports:
   error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
   error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
   error: Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports: netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
   error: Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports:
   error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
   error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
   error: One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
   log  : Writing lock file to disk. Path: /tmp/staged/app/src/MyProject.Utility/project.lock.json
   log  : ./src/MyProject.Core/project.json
   log  : Restore failed in 11621ms.
   log  : ./src/MyProject.Utility/project.json
   log  : Restore failed in 11692ms.
   error: Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 supports:
   error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
   error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
   error: One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.

   warn :  dotnetCloudantWebstarter (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json (>= 1.0.0-rc2-final)
   error: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0 supports:
   error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
   error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
   error: Package cloudscribe.Web.Pagination 1.0.3 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package cloudscribe.Web.Pagination 1.0.3 supports:
   error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
   error:   - net452 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2)
   error:   - net46 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6)
   error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
   error: Package NonFactors.Grid.Core.Mvc6 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package NonFactors.Grid.Core.Mvc6 1.0.0 supports:
   error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
   error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
   error: One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
   log  : Writing lock file to disk. Path: /tmp/staged/app/src/dotnetCloudantWebstarter/project.lock.json
   log  : ./src/dotnetCloudantWebstarter/project.json
   log  : Restore failed in 12032ms.
   error: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures 1.0.0 supports:
   error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
   error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
   error: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 1.0.0 supports:
   error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
   error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
   error: One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
   log  : Writing lock file to disk. Path: /tmp/staged/app/MyProject.Core/project.lock.json
   log  : ./MyProject.Core/project.json
   log  : Restore failed in 3423ms.
   Errors in ./MyProject.Utility/project.json
       Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 supports:
         - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
         - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
       One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
       Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 1.0.0 supports:
         - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
         - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
       One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
       Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports: netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
       Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports:
         - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
         - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
       One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
       Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 supports:
         - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
         - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
       One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
       Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0 supports:
         - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
         - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
       Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports: netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
       Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports:
         - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
         - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
   Errors in ./src/MyProject.Utility/project.json
       Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports: netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
       Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports:
         - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
         - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
       One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
       Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 supports:
         - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
         - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
       One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
         - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
         - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
       Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports: netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
       Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports:
         - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
         - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
       One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
   Errors in ./src/dotnetCloudantWebstarter/project.json
       Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports: netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
       Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports:
         - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
         - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
       One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
       Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 supports:
         - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
         - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
       One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
       Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0 supports:
         - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
         - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
       Package cloudscribe.Web.Pagination 1.0.3 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package cloudscribe.Web.Pagination 1.0.3 supports:
         - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
         - net452 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2)
         - net46 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6)
         - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
       Package NonFactors.Grid.Core.Mvc6 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package NonFactors.Grid.Core.Mvc6 1.0.0 supports:
         - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
         - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
       One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
   Errors in ./MyProject.Core/project.json
       Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 supports:
         - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
         - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
       One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
       Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures 1.0.0 supports:
         - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
         - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
       Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 1.0.0 supports:
         - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
         - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
       One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
   FAILED: command failed, exit status 1
   FAILED: Restoring dependencies with Dotnet CLI failed, command failed, exit status 1
Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed


FAILED
BuildpackCompileFailed

TIP: use 'cf logs MyProject --recent' for more information

Finished: FAILED
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Adding an import for `netstandard1.6` in your frameworks section of `project.json` should fix this issue.

Example frameworks section:

```
"frameworks": {
  "netcoreapp1.0": {
    "imports": [
      "dotnet5.6",
      "portable-net45+win8",
      "netstandard1.6"
    ]
  }
}
```

***Update***

Your project.json is also including packages from `"1.0.0-rc2-final"` and `"1.0.0"`, that will almost certainly cause conflicts when restoring dependencies of those packages.  You should change the `"1.0.0-rc2-final"` references to `"1.0.0"` and the `"1.0.0-rc2-002702"` references to `"1.0.0-rc3-003121"`.  After you've done that, clear you nuget packages cache using `nuget locals all -clear` to ensure these old RC2 packages aren't leftover in the cache.

Comment: Danial Thanks for Response.